# WCF ServiceModel.CommunicationException when called internally

Tags: c#, wcf

I added the reference of an external wcf service to my project. I can consume this service normally, but trying to consume internally (on the same server as the service is exposed to) I am getting the error below:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'RETMALHA'. OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'RETMALHARESPONSE' and namespace 'http://200.XXX.XXX.XX:81/'. Found node type 'Element' with name 'RETMALHARESPONSE' and namespace 'http://192.168.XXX.XXX:81/' ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'RETMALHARESPONSE' and namespace 'http://200.XXX.XXX.XX:81/'. Found node type 'Element' with name 'RETMALHARESPONSE' and namespace 'http://192.168.XXX.XXX:81/'

Given this message I manually manipulated the automatically generated "References.cs" file and changed the address of the Namespaces that had 200.XXX.XXX.XX:81 to 192.168.XXX.XXX:81. After this change internally began to work, but externally no longer works.
[image]

This service was not created by me, I am just consuming. And the application I'm developing will consume internally and externally.

Is there anything that I could make the client side flexible? Or do I have to talk to the service owner? What's wrong?

Comment: Does the namespace get generated based on the IP address of the host?

Answer (score 0):

WCF‘s SOAP envelope needs to serialize and deserialize data as it is transmitted between the client-side and the server. This requires that for custom data types (data conventions), it is important to ensure that the data type has the same fully qualified name on both the client-side and the server-side, including its namespace attribute. In general, this values should be constant for a particular endpoint address (when we call the service by adding service reference), Please make sure you use the right service endpoint to add the service.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.